# Synonym requests

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

These tags seem close enough to me to be merged:

[google-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-account) & [google-accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-accounts), and

[user-accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-accounts), and [account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account).

My apologies if this isn't the right course of action, but *I* can't do anything about it, so I thought it best to bring it up to the people who can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[google-accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-accounts) has been merged into [google-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-account)

[user-accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-accounts) has been merged into [account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account)